# Load Linux library through a Windows client

Tags: java, linux, terminal

several years I used to come on the bible of coding and I have (maybe) a question rarely asked. First of all thanks to all people which takes time to answer us.

I have a network with a Linux server and some Windows clients. On the server I have to use a Java application (I don't have source code) but it's hard to use it on the server : graphic card drivers are not update then the resolution of the screen is "small" and not expandable. It's a problem because layouts of the app are not dynamics then some important buttons are not displayed (is it so hard to use a JScrollPane ???). And I don't really want to learn how many times I have to use Tab for each hidden button.

Then one solution is to launch the app on a Windows client through MobaXterm. It works well but at one moment a process need a library.
I tried to launch the app by adding the library path of the library, a *.so file, but didn't work.

The question is : a java application installed on Linux and launched through a windows client need *.so or *.dll library ?

Thanks.

Florent